# python pptx show category values in pie chart

Tags: python, categories, pie-chart, python-pptx

How can I switch the parameter marked red below (in English: "show categories" in python pptx for a pie chart? Any ideas appreciated.

[image: MS Powerpoint parameter dialog box]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a feature request for this: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/242

In the mean time one can work around this by setting the label text from python, for example like this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE, XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.util import Inches

# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['West', 'East', 'North', 'South', 'Other']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (0.135, 0.324, 0.180, 0.235, 0.126))

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.PIE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
).chart

chart.has_legend = False

# set labels to contain category and value
for i in range(len(chart_data.categories)):
    point = chart.series[0].points[i]
    point.data_label.text_frame.text = "{}: {:.0%}".format(chart_data.categories[i].label, chart.series[0].values[i])
    point.data_label.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Showing the category names in data labels was added as part of [release 0.6.16](https://pypi.org/project/python-pptx/). You can show it by setting `show_category_name` to `True` in the Chart's data_labels.

```
chart.plots[0].data_labels.show_category_name = True
```

There's also a few more options that were added to data labels, you can see the full list in the [library](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#datalabels-objects).